# Regular expression is not working for number validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have one validatin which allows 17 digits and otherwise is throughs an error, i wrote some code but its not working.Here is my code.

```
  function validateRedeemPin(){
        var pin = document.getElementById('epayPinNumber').value;  
        var pattern = /^\d{17}$/;  
        var validPin = pin.match(pattern);  
        if(!validPin){ 
        alert("Please enter a valid 17 digit PIN number to redeem.");
        return false'
       }
 }
```

Here is fiddle [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nsne/)

Comment: Don't you think that the first step should be resolving syntax errors in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single quote after your `return false` statement.  Also, your function should be defined already if you're going to refer to it in the html tag, so you should wrap it in the head tag (left hand panel in jsfiddle): See [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nsne/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code last line unwanted single quote **return false'**. Thats why code not work otherwise perfect.

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nsne/8/)**</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
function validateRedeemPin(){    
        var pin = document.getElementById('PinNumber').value;  
        var pattern = /^\d{17}$/;  
        var validPin = pin.match(pattern);  
        if(!validPin){ 
        alert("Please enter a valid 17 digit PIN number to redeem.");
        return false
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above mentioned typos, input has to be summited in a form and then processed.

Here is an example of a form validation with JS.

http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/validation.shtml

Good luck

:)

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes in you code:-
You missed the end tag of input.

```
<input id="PinNumber" name="PinNumber" type="text">
now adding end tag of input.
<input id="PinNumber" name="PinNumber" type="text"/>
```

And remove the single apostrophe(') at end of "return false" statement.

```
return false' //this will not parse correctly. so remove
return false;
```

Mistake in your jsFIddle:-
Change the "onLoad" condition to "No wrap - in head" option. so this function will be added in header section. Or define function with this following syntax.

```
validateRedeemPin = function() {
  //code goes here...
}
```